# Overloaded global new/delete issue, C++ gcc

Tags: c++, gcc

I am reading Scott Meyers' *Effective C++* book and I came across `::operator new` and `delete` overload issue. I tried to  overload `new` and `delete` myself, but `delete` function gets called twice, what is the problem?

Following is the code in question:

```
int ob=0; //counts how many objects are created via overloaded new

void* operator new(size_t size, string st) 
{
    cout<<st<<endl;
    cout<<"this is overloaded version of new, new allocates "<<size<<endl;
    ob++;
    return malloc(size); 
 }

 void operator delete(void * ptr)
 {
    free((void*)ptr);
    ob--;
    cout<<"end of destruction"<<endl;
 }

 int main()
 {
    int* ptr = new("hello world") int(5);
    cout<<*ptr<<endl;
    cout<<ob<<" objects exist"<<endl;
    delete(ptr);
    cout<<ob<<" objects exist"<<endl;
    return 0;
 }
```

As a result a value of `ob` is -1, why is that?

Comment: The global `operator delete` is being used to free the memory allocated for the temporary `std::string` created from `"hello world"`.

Comment: Define another `operator new` that only takes the `size`, and also increments `ob`.